# RedHat 5: HP Server ethtool not working

Tags: networking, redhat, hp, ethtool

I am trying to check/change my network card speed settings with RedHat 5 and a Proliant G6 server from HP.
On eth0 I can not really use ethtool - it just says Link detected. The network card is a Broadcom NetXtremee II BCM5709.

Is there any other tool from HP for this task.

The output of setting the speed is:"Can not get current device settings: Operation not supported - not settings speed not setting duplex".

Comment: Why can't you use ethtool?  What options did you use and what was the output?

Comment: I have updated the output/error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, some NIC's work with ethtool, others with mii-tool. Both have approximately the same functionality. That is, see if mii-tool works for your card.

Answer (score 0):

What is the minor version of RHEL 5 ? There are a lot work done for  Broadcom NetXtremee II BCM5709 in the kernel shipped with RHEL5.6 and higher. Upgrade the kernel by using following commands

## yum update kernel ----->> if system is registered to RHN.

Else download the kernel and install using

## rpm -ivh latest_Kernel_rpm

DO NOT use "rpm -Uvh" command